# Automatic form submit when choosing an item in ngAutocomplete (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete, google-places-api

I am using the the module ngAutocomplete which searches for places as you type. The suggested places shows up in a drop down and then when you click on an item it will insert the text onto the form and then you have to hit the submit button. Is there a way to have the form automatically submit after i choose an item from the list?

Answer (score 1):

You can use $watch on the ng-model wich is binded to your autocompleted place.

```
$scope.$watch('myPlace', function() {
  $scope.submit();
});
```

Comment: i placed a console.log("hello") inside the submit function and while i was typing, it was logging "hello" multiple times when i wasn't finished typing. This is going to be a problem because the function is actually suppose to invoke multiple API requests. Would there be a way to have it submit only when an item is actually clicked from the autocomplete form?

Comment: Oh of course you're right ...
In [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24636711/google-places-autocomplete-with-angular-js) it seems that there is a 'places_change' event. Is it the library you are using ? You could listen to that event and submit at that moment.